# What would you call this angle?

Tags: single-word-requests

In painting (as well as in photography, I suspect) there's full face, profile, half-profile, and three quarters. Here's an example demonstrating three of the four (Portrait of Charles I, the one that got his head chopped off in *Twenty Years After*, by Van Dyck):

[image]

But what do you call this (typical Whistler, by the way):

[image]

Comment: Dorsal profile with a half twist.

Answer (score 2):

This can be correctly described as:

Standing, rear view, full body length, over the shoulder in profile.

Or just "over the shoulder".

"Three quarters" is usually called oblique and "dorsal" makes me think of a fish...